# When HDD becomes full, how to create a symbolic link to the data store on another disk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Linux Ubuntu machine which has an X GB hard disk. There is folder, say, `/opt/software/data`. The disk `/dev/sda1` is almost full and I have attached another disk at `/dev/sda2` which is mounted at `/hdd2`.

Is it possible for me to link the folders `/opt/software/data` with `/hdd2/software/data` so, that every file get stored in the `/hdd2/software/data` but may be referred from the `/opt/software/data`?

I can't do a reinstall of the software that creates this data, to change the default location of storage.

Comment: Please edit the question, it's hard to understand what's going on there. And please use commas and formatting!

Comment: @gronostaj Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Stop the application
2. copy the data from the old to the new location: `rsync -av /opt/software/data /hdd2`
3. rename the old data directory: `mv /opt/software/data /opt/software/data.old`
4. create a symlink so `/opt/software/data` points to `hdd2`: `ln -s /hdd2 /opt/software/data`
5. start the application
6. if all works well: `rm /opt/software/data.old`

Comment: thanks man, I'll try it, and mark it an answer if it clicks out for me

Comment: why do you not simply do `mv /opt/software/data /hdd2`?

Comment: I would add to this `step 0. run the program to check it works and how it handles login/user accounts etc`.